# How to fix a downloads directory in UBUNTU 18.04?

Tags: directory, downloads, system

I lost the downloads directory by mistake. Updates did not replace it. I do not want to reinstall UBUNTU as a solution to fix this issue. I am using UBUNTU 18.04. I get a message asking me to use blueman-services to configure a downloads directory but I couldn't. Is there a solution other than reinstalling UBUNTU?

Comment: From terminal type in `mkdir ~/Downloads`

Comment: What do you mean by 'lost'?

Comment: I read Mchid's answer and used it before I see Terrance above. Yet I did that only today, meaning Terrance was there but I did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

I used information coming from others and read other's answers on how to use bluman-services. In the transfer page there was a window opening for selections about receiving "incoming files". When I clicked on it, selected "downloads", then: apply. This resulted in disappearance of the message saying that a downloads directory does not exist, but the downloads folder did not work as it did not receive incoming files. The solution came from Mchid suggestion to use the following command in Terminal: 
***mkdir downloads*** 
keep it and reboot